# Error Detection and Error Handling in ESP8266 while communicating with Raspberry Pi through MQTT

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, raspberry-pi3, esp8266, nodemcu

I am using **MQTT** to communicate between **ESP8266** and **Raspberry Pi** and I am sending multiple strings from ESP8266 to Raspberry Pi. So i want to know that is there any functions or something that can **detect error** while sending data(String) to Raspberry Pi (if there occurred an error). And if so then how can i **handle that error** ?

This is my code in NodeMCU

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial NodeMCU(D2,D3);  

const char* ssid = "raspi-webgui";           // wifi ssid
const char* password =  "ChangeMe";         // wifi password
const char* mqttServer2= "192.168.43.164";  // IP adress Raspberry Pi
const int mqttPort = 1883;
const char* mqttUser = ""; 
const char* mqttPassword = "";

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);
  NodeMCU.begin(4800);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

if(!WiFi.status()){
    Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network with ");
    }else{
      Serial.print("Failed to Connect to the raspberry pi with IP : ");
      Serial.println(mqttServer2);
      }


  client.setServer(mqttServer2, mqttPort);
  client.setCallback(callback);

  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Connecting to raspberry pi...");

    if (client.connect("ESP8266Client", mqttUser, mqttPassword )) {

      Serial.print("connected to the raspberry pi whith IP : ");
      Serial.println(mqttServer2);
      Serial.print("Loca IP Address of NodeMCU : ");
      Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

    } else {

      Serial.print("failed with state ");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      delay(2000);

    }
  }

}



void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {

  Serial.print("Message from raspberry pi : ");

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  String Topic_Str(topic);

  if( Topic_Str == "t_data"){

        String a_data = "Send String to raspberry pi.";

        //
        //
        //
        //
        //
        **// So here i am sending string to raspberry pi. Now how could i know that the raspberry pi had got the actual value or string
        // and there is no error , no bit has changed during communication.**
        //
        //
        //
        //
        //


        delay(5000);
        client.publish("a_data", (char*) a_data.c_str());

    }

}

void loop() {

    client.subscribe("t_data");
    delay(1000);
    client.loop();

}
```

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60912912/edit) the question to show your code and then somebody can probably explain how to add some error handling. Also what type of errors are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

First up, a 5 second delay in you message callback is a REALLY bad idea, these callbacks should run as quickly as possible, you are currently injecting 6 seconds between each client.loop when a message is received.

Second from the docs:

> boolean **publish** (topic, payload)
>
> Publishes a string message to the specified topic.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - topic - the topic to publish to (const char[])
> - payload -
>   the message to publish (const char[])
>
> Returns
>
> - false - publish failed, either connection lost, or message too large
> - true - publish succeeded

So `client.publish()` will return `true` if the publish was successful and `false` if it failed.

(I modified the doc slightly, the it says the return type should be int, but it's actually a boolean when checking the src and it makes sense for the listed return options)

Comment: Okay. Thank you. and is there any possible way to know what kind of error occurred?